# How to change url redirect by Query String in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com">
```

I want to something like this

http://localhost/?url=google.com => google.com

Comment: What have you tried already? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to split the google.com part from the whole URL. 
Assign the desired url to a string

`var urlString = "http://localhost/?url=google.com";`

Then use the [`String.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to create an array split by the `=` sign

`var splitStringArr = urlString.split("=");`

The google.com part would be the second element of the split string array.

```
console.log(splitStringArr[1])
```

Output:

> google.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myUrl = 'http://localhost/?url=google.com'

if(myUrl.includes('url=')){
 let result = myUrl.split('url=')[1];
  console.log('the result is:', result);
}else{
  console.log('no result');
}
```

this one of the solultion, i think you shouldn't forget myUrl.includes to prevent undefined value;